# OpenAPI validating proxy

Tags: swagger, reverse-proxy, openapi

Let's say I have some OpenAPI (swagger) service description in YAML or JSON.

What are HTTP proxy servers, which can validate actual request and response against description?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a couple of solutions for validating requests and reponses in [this great overview of OpenAPI tools](https://openapi.tools/).

Answer (score 1):

As of Mar 2021, I found these:

- Prism by Spotlight: it can work as an API mock server or [validation proxy](https://meta.stoplight.io/docs/prism/docs/guides/03-validation-proxy.md)
- [OpenAPI-cop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-cop) - it's backed by [openapi-backend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-backend)
- Or, you could build one in node.js by using a validator middleware, e.g.

  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-validator-middleware
  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-openapi-validator